# Video tag error HTML5

Tags: html, video, html5-video, mp4

I'm working on embedding a local video file. The video is located in the same folder as the html file.The video file was originally wmv format but I reformatted it to the mp4 format.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="Shredder_Training_R2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

The video doesn't appear and when I looked into the issue, it says that there is a "404 (Not Found)" error. I'm not quite sure why this is occurring, like I said the video file is found in the same folder so why would it not be found?

Any tips?

Comment: Verify your webserver can serve video/mp4 file types. You don't say what web server are you running but for example in Apache web server there must be a rule like `AddType video/mp4 .mp4` enabled in `mime.types` config file or somewhere.

Comment: Can you view the MP4 by accessing it through the browser directly?
E.g. http://yourdomain.name/path/Shredder_Training_R2.mp4

Comment: It was the web server issue. I don't have access to configure any server files but thanks to understanding the issue I was able to send the problem to someone who did and we got it fixed.

Thanks @Hokusai